# Dúvidas em excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Estou criando uma macro onde faz envio de emails, porém estou preso em um processo.

Queria saber se é possível criar uma coluna onde eu selecione um motivo de pendência, por exemplo "falta de rg" que ao ser selecionada, ela traz um script pronto e automaticamente é inserido no corpo do email.

Estou utilizando um código bem simples que encontrei na net..

```
Baseado no código disponibilizado em http://guiadoexcel.com.br/
Function EnviaEmail()
Dim iMsg, iConf, Flds

Set iMsg = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
Set iConf = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")
Set Flds = iConf.Fields

schema = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/"
Flds.Item(schema & "sendusing") = 2
'Configura o smtp
Flds.Item(schema & "smtpserver") = "smtp.gmail.com"
'Configura a porta de envio de email
Flds.Item(schema & "smtpserverport") = 465
Flds.Item(schema & "smtpauthenticate") = 1
'Configura o email do remetente
Flds.Item(schema & "sendusername") = "maximilianomeyer48@gmail.com"
'Configura a senha do email remetente
Flds.Item(schema & "sendpassword") = "senha do seu e-mail"
Flds.Item(schema & "smtpusessl") = 1
Flds.Update

With iMsg
   'Email do destinatário
   .To = "max@desenvolveweb.com.br"
   'Seu email
   .From = xpto@gmail.com
   'Título do email
   .Subject = "Isto é um teste de Envio de e-mail"
   'Mensagem do e-mail, você pode enviar formatado em HTML
   .HTMLBody = "Mensagem enviada com o gmail"
   'Seu nome ou apelido
   .Sender = "Teste"
   'Nome da sua organização
   .Organization = "Aprender Excel"
   'e-mail de responder para
   .ReplyTo = "maximilianomeyer48@gmail.com"
   'Anexo a ser enviado na mensagem. Retire a aspa da linha abaixo e coloque o endereço do arquivo
   .AddAttachment ("c:/fatura.txt")
   Set .Configuration = iConf
   .Send
End With

Set iMsg = Nothing
Set iConf = Nothing
Set Flds = Nothing
End Function

Sub disparar()
   EnviaEmail
   MsgBox "O e-mail foi disparado com sucesso!", vbOKOnly, "e-mail enviado"
End Sub
```

Comment: Faltou descrever o problema. Tem algo errado com o código?

Comment: É possível, você pode realizar de várias maneiras. Uma delas é com a utilização de formulários (Userform).

Comment: Outra forma seria usar um simples If. Se for "falta de rg" ele chama uma função que insere tal script, por exemplo. (p.s. Esse código foi retirado do meu site, olha o meu e-mail ali euhuehe Valeu pela audiência)

Comment: Boa amigos,  queria saber só se era possível ser feito. Agora irei atrás dos meios. Sim Max, tirei do seu site mesmo, ajudou muito! Valeu haha